# Can't import MySQL database due to syntax error

Tags: mysql, linux

But why?
I've imported it in OS X and on another Linux machine,
this one however plain refuses..

Where am I going wrong?

Output:

mysql> mysql -u root -p explore < /tmp/explore.sql;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -p explore < /tmp/explore.sql' at line 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to run a **shell** command from the MySQL command line interpreter. You need to run that from BASH (or any other shell), no the MYSQL command prompt.

Like this in Linux:

```
$ mysql -u root -p explore < /tmp/explore.sql;
```

Like this in Windows:

```
C:\> mysql -u root -p explore < c:\tmp\explore.sql;
```

Comment: That... Didn't make sense to me. It was, however, as simple as that. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

try to execute this

```
source /tmp/explore.sql;
```

after logging in mysql prompt

or

get out from the mysql prompt you are already there and run the command you are trying.
Thanks